# Почему не удаляется коммит в git bash

Tags: git

Почему когда я ввожу git log у меня вылезает один единственный коммит в ветке main, как его удалить?

Comment: Перенесите ветку main на один коммит раньще

Comment: Хорошая практика - сделать реверт коммита. Переписывание истории - плохая идея

Comment: Непонятно к какому результату нужно прийти? Какой смысл в репозитории без коммитов?

Comment: @AlexeyTen мне нужно чтобы когда я ввожу git log консоль была пустая

Comment: Зачем? Ну удалите репозиторий и создайте заново.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае всё просто.

```
git reset HEAD~1 --soft
```

Удалит последний коммит. `HEAD~1` это диапазон, где `HEAD` указывает на последний коммит, а `1` означает сколько коммитов отступить назад. Флаг `--soft` нужен, чтобы `git` оставил файлы и не откатывал их.

**Но стоит учесть**, что если коммит до удаления был запушен в удалённый репозиторий, то нужно либо выполнить [force push](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12610763/13129945), что не рекомендуется при командной разработке, либо создать [revert коммит](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)

Comment: Не удалит коммит, а перенесет ветку main на один коммит раньше.

Comment: @user7860670 Возможно, но это то что нужно автору. Если не удаляет коммит, то это предполагает, что его можно вернуть?

Comment: Да, его можно вернуть, передвинув ветку обратно на этот коммит.

Comment: @Данила Отметьте ответ как решение, если он отвечает на ваш вопрос